# SlackBot: Dialog is not invoked from App home

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, slack, slack-api, aws-serverless

Error invoking a dialog from Slack new app home using a button. Using AWS lambda and NodeJS.
Link followed: https://api.slack.com/tutorials/app-home-with-modal

Sample API call:

`POST https://slack.com/api/views.open`

Body:

```
{"view": "{'type':'modal','title':{'type':'plain_text','text':'Request leave','emoji':true},'submit':{'type':'plain_text','text':'Submit','emoji':true},'close':{'type':'plain_text','text':'Cancel','emoji':true},'blocks':[{'type':'divider'},{'type':'input','element':{'type':'datepicker','placeholder':{'type':'plain_text','text':'Select a date','emoji':true}},'label':{'type':'plain_text','text':'Start date','emoji':true}},{'type':'input','optional':true,'element':{'type':'datepicker','placeholder':{'type':'plain_text','text':'Select a date','emoji':true}},'label':{'type':'plain_text','text':'End date','emoji':true}},{'type':'input','label':{'type':'plain_text','text':'Reason','emoji':true},'element':{'type':'plain_text_input','multiline':true},'optional':true}]}",
  "trigger_id": "9%%%%00d5bb3e5"
}
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type => application/json; charset=iso-8859-1
Authorization => Bearer  xoxb-94*******
```

Error:

`{"ok":false,"error":"dispatch_failed"}` in the browser network tab

Update: `http_service_error` when I use `slash command` with `dialog.open` / `views.open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const web = new WebClient(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
(async () => {
    await web.views.open({
        trigger_id: body.trigger_id,
        view: {<my block>},
    });
})();
```

This worked!